# How to calculate CPU Usage without WMI and Performance Counter in C#?

Tags: c#, cpu-usage

I have been searching the solution to get CPU Usage percentage without WMI and Performance Counter, But I didn't find out any solution which works perfectly.

I have tried to get "Process.TotalProcessorTime" but it gives the time consume by process not the actual CPU Usage.

WMI and Performance counter I can't use due to performance impact.

Can anyone suggest some option in C#?

Comment: If your target OS is Windows and your programming environment is C# then I don't think there would be any alternatives.

Comment: @Transcendent Yes I am using C# and OS is Windows.

Comment: You can't get that close to hardware using C# when targeting Windows. If you were writing it for Linux and you were not using C# then that would be a lot different.

Comment: Thank You @Transcendent for your input.